# Nesting [innerHTML] in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I 'nest' `innerHTML` bindings? Is it a sanitation problem?

I am using angular to create a website to play chess. I am dynamically creating a table and putting it into the component with: `<div [innerHTML]="board | safeHTML">` where `board` with a string with the HTML for the table in and `safeHTML` is a pipe that bypasses sanitisation so the HTML isn't just read as a string. The code to generate the table is at the bottom of the post.

I would like to then be able to change the contents of each cell in the table.

Here is an example cell:

```
<td id="n${uniqueNumber}" class="board" [innerHTML]="boardValues.${uniqueNumber}">{{boardValues.${uniqueNumber}}}</td>
```

`boardValues` is an object that contains all of the cell data.

The table correctly displays when bound with `[innerHTML]` however the cells don't and `[innerHTML]` is displayed as an attribute [(e.g. this image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR7e2.png). Similarly  `{{boardValues.value}}` shows up as plain text rather than the value.

How can I 'nest' `innerHTML` bindings? Is it a sanitation problem?

My html:

Running that doesn't work but it shows my main loops (the important one is `generateBoard`)
[Here is a stack blitz project that sort of works but doesn't have formatting for some reason. Still shows my issue](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ujrgx2?file=src/app/app.component.css)

```js
generateBoard(n, playColour) {
  var tblBuild = ""
  var tblFooter = "<tr><td id=\"blank\"></td>"
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    tblFooter += `<th class="coordinates letters">${String.fromCharCode(97+i)}</th>`
  }
  tblFooter += "</tr>"
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    tblBuild += `<tr class="n${n-i+1}">`
    tblBuild += `<th class="coordinates numbers">${n-i+1}</th>`
    for (var j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
      var idValue = `n${8*(n-i)+j}`
      //want to assign the innerHTML to an object
      tblBuild += `<td id="n${idValue}" class="board" [innerHTML]="boardValues.${idValue}">{{boardValues.${idValue}}}</td>`
    }
    tblBuild += ("</tr>")
  }
  var tbl = "<table id=\"board\" class= \"board " + playColour + "\"" + "<tbody>" + tblBuild + "</tbody>" + tblFooter + "</table>"
  console.log(tbl)
  return tbl
}

generateBoardValues(n) {
  interface LooseObject {
    [key: string]: any
  }
  var boardValues: LooseObject = {}
  console.log("running generateBoardvalues")
  console.log("n", n)
  for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j <= n; j++) {
      boardValues[`n${8*(n-i)+j}`] = `n${8*(n-i)+j}`
      console.log("generating boardValues", boardValues[`n${8*(n-i)+j}`])
    }
  }
  boardValues.n15 = "maually set"
  console.log("n15", boardValues.n15)
  console.log(Object.keys(boardValues).sort((a, b) => Number(a.slice(1)) - Number(b.slice(1)))) //sorted values
  return boardValues
}

n = 7
boardValues = generateBoardValues(n)
board = generateBoard(n, "white")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<p [innerHTML]="boardValues.n12"></p> <!--Works-->
<div [innerHTML]="board | safeHTML"> <!-- displays table but not desired cell contents-->
```

Answer (score 0):

This approche is very expensive. I wouldn't use `innerHTML` in your case. You should handle this in your template file and use `*ngFor`.